# prove that $\mu$ is a measure $\sigma$-finite.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ a countable subset. Let $a: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$   any function. For $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ define  $\mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E\cap A} a(x)$.

(a) Prove that  $\mu$ is a measure $σ$-finite on $(\mathbb{R},P(\mathbb{R}))$

(B) find Lebesgue decomposition  $\mu= \mu_{a}+ \mu_{s}$ of $\mu$  with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. ($\mu_{a} \ll \lambda$ and $\mu_{s}\perp \lambda$)

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

a) $A$ is countable and $a(x)$ is finite.

b) $\mu$ is concentrated on $A$ and $\lambda(A) = 0$.

Comment: but not necessarily E is countable.

Comment: @AlexanderOsorio Ah, I meant $A$ (and therefore $A \cap E \subset A$ too). Fixed now.

Comment: But E ∩ A can have infinite elements. thus µ(E) is infinite

Comment: That's OK. $\mu$ is required to be $\sigma$-finite, not finite. $\sigma$-finite means any $E$ is a countable union of measurable sets of finite measure. What's the measure of each $\{x\}$ where $x \in E$?